# Solve some equation in scala using pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm very new to Scala, and while reading the [ScalaTutorial.pdf](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaTutorial.pdf) Section 6: *Case classes and pattern matching*

I find no information on how to run its example which is:

```
package my

abstract class Tree
case class Sum(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree
case class Var(n: String) extends Tree 
case class Const(i: Int) extends Tree 

object TestTree {

  type Environment = String => Int

  def eval(t: Tree, env: Environment): Int = t match {
    case Sum(l, r) => eval(l, env) + eval(r, env)
    case Var(n) => env(n)
    case Const(v) => v
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]){

    val s : Sum = Sum(Var("x"), Const(10))
    // Then how to define a variable of type environment to pass it to the `eval` function:
    //eval(s, Environment) ??
  }
}
```

I don't know how to pass the Environment to the `eval` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Environment = String => Int
```

This says that the type `Environment` is equal to the type `String => Int`, i.e. the type of functions that take a `String` and return an `Int`. It should be noted that in Scala a map is a kind of function (which is to say `Map[K,V]` is a subtype of `K => V`). So any function that takes a function as an argument can also take a map instead.

So to use `eval` you can pass it a function of type `String => Int`, which might either be an actual function that you defined and that takes a string and returns an int, or a map that maps strings to integers.

Comment: Right, except that there's no pointer involved.  Functions are first class objects in Scala, and can be named and referenced just like anything else.